# Is it possible to process objects in a Google Cloud Storage bucket in FIFO order?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In my web app, I need to pull objects from gcs one by one and process them.
So the question is,
**"How do I send a request to gcs to get the next unprocessed object?"**

What I’d like to do is to simply rely on the sort order provided by gcs and then just process the objects in this sorted list one by one.
That way, I only need to keep track of the last processed item in my app.
I’d like to rely on the sort order provided by the timeCreated timestamp on each individual object in the bucket.

When I query my bucket via the JSON API, I notice that the objects are returned sorted by timeCreated from oldest to newest.

For example, this query ...

[image]

returns this list ...

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00001.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:47.506Z"
  },
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00002.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:49.320Z"
  },
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00003.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:50.228Z"
  },
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00004.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:51.377Z"
  },
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00005.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:51.778Z"
  },
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00006.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:52.817Z"
  },
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00007.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:53.868Z"
  },
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00008.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:54.925Z"
  },
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00009.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:58.426Z"
  },
  {
   "name": "cars_train/00010.jpg",
   "timeCreated": "2016-03-23T19:19:59.323Z"
  }
 ]
}
```

This sort order by timeCreated is exactly what I need, though I’m not certain if I can rely on this always being true?

So, I could code my app to process this list by simply searching for the first timeCreated value greater than the last object that processed.

The problem is this list can be very large and searching through a huge list every single time the user presses the NEXT button is too computationally expensive.

I would like to be able to specify in my query to gcs to filter the list so that I return only the single item that I need.

The API does allow me to set the maxResults returned to a value of 1.

However, I do not see an option that would allow me to return only objects whose timeCreated value is greater than the value I specified.

I think what I am trying to do is probably fairly common, so I’m guessing that a solution may exist for this problem.

One work around for this problem is to physically move an object that has been processed to another bucket. 
That way the first item in the list would always be the newest one and I could simply send the request with maxCount=1.

But this adds complexity because it forces me have have 2 separate buckets for every project instead of 1.

Is there a way to filter this list of objects to only include ones whose timeCreated date is above a specified value?

In MySQL, it might be something like ...

```
SELECT name
FROM bucket
WHERE timeCreated > X
ORDER BY timeCreated
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure object change notifications on the bucket, and get a notification each time a new object arrives. That would allow you to process new objects without scanning a long listing each time. It also avoids the problem that listing a bucket is only eventually consistent (so, recently uploaded objects may not show up immediately when you list objects; I don't know if that's a problem for your app).

Details about object change notification are documented at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification.

Answer (score 1):

Object listing in GCS is **not** sorted by timeCreated. Object listing results are always in alphabetical order. In your example, those two things merely happen to catch up.

If you want to get a list of objects in the order they were uploaded, you must ensure that each object has a name alphabetically later than the name of any object uploaded before it. Even then, however, you must take care, as object listing is eventually consistent, which means that objects you upload may not immediately show up in a listing.

If some ordering of objects is critically important, it would be a good idea to maintain a separate index of the objects and their timestamps in a separate data structure, perhaps populated via object change notifications as Mike suggested.